# Qgis-Replace file path in attribute table 'invalid Expression'

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, replace

I wan't to replace my filepath in the attribute table but I'm always getting an invalid expression. I already tried to double the backslashes but I didn't work out.

[image]

Comment: There is a whitespace at the beginning of "Dateiname". Could that be it? What does the invalid message say if you click on it?

Comment: Can we have the message and see the path in order to try and solve your problem ?

Comment: Thx you for your help, i had to do it in the table calculator and not in the expression editor. my fault but thx. and with double backslashes